# Define the following modules to display the system’s summary.

Tags: c

(a) a module to display the author(s) name against each shell command located at /bin/
(b) a module to collect CPU utilization percentage in an interval of 20 seconds. Execute
the module for 5 minutes. Store system time and CPU utilization count to a file (e.g.,
utlCount.txt).
(c) a module to display CPU utilization percentage by a specified user (e.g.mysql) in an
interval of 10 seconds.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
        void main() {
             system("ls -l --author /bin | awk '{print$5\nprint$10}'");
             system("mpstat 2 4 | cat > a.txt");
             char str[30];
             printf("enter the user name");
             scanf("%s",str);
             system("mpstat 2 4 |  grep ('str')");

   }
```

why it is showing error in 3rd one?

Comment: `char cmd[256]; sprintf(cmd,"mpstat 2 4 |  grep ('%s')",str); system(cmd);` So you have to put the string from the user in the command you issue the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot include contents of `str`   in           `system("mpstat 2 4 |  grep ('str')");`this way.

Also `grep` will not accept `( and )` brackets. Refer the below code as an example.

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>
        void main() {
             system("ls -l --author /bin | awk '{print$5\nprint$10}'"); 
             system("mpstat 2 4 | cat > a.txt");
             char str[30];
             printf("enter the user name");
             scanf("%s",str);
             char command[100];
             sprintf(command,"mpstat 2 4 |  grep \"%s\"",str);
             system(command);

   }
```

Comment: sprintf(command,"top -d 10 |  grep \"%s\" | awk '{print$2\nprint$9}'",str);
    system(command);  why it is not working

Comment: `sprintf(command,"top -d 10 | grep \"%s\" | awk '{print $2,$9}'",str);`

Comment: `awk` doesn't take `\n` and `\t` as its argument.